# How to make Knockout a knockout visible tag use display:none !important

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js, twitter-bootstrap-3, knockout-3.0

I have a site using both knockout and bootstrap, I need to use the knockout visible data binding to add and remove certain elements based on a given criteria, however , when knockout add's the `style="display:none"` to the `div` it gets overridden by bootstrap as the `hidden-md` and `hidden-lg` use `display:block !important` on smaller screens.

```
 <div class="col-xs-1 hidden-md hidden-lg" data-bind="visible: BooleanValue"></div>
```

Is there a simple way to make knockout use `style="display:none !important"` so that my values aren't shown?

Cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the `css` binding and add a style rule to (the bottom) of your style guide:

```js
ko.applyBindings({booleanValue: ko.observable(true)});
```

```css
.block {
  display: block !important;
}

.hide-important {
  display: none !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>


<div class="block" data-bind="visible: booleanValue">
  visible binding
</div>

<div class="block" data-bind="css: {'hide-important': !booleanValue()}">
  css binding
</div>

<button data-bind="click: booleanValue.bind(null, !booleanValue())">toggle</button>
```

Alternatively, you could implement a custom visible binding:

```js
ko.bindingHandlers['importantVisible'] = {
  'update': function(element, valueAccessor) {
    var show = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
    if (!show)
      element.style.setProperty("display", "none", "important")
    else
      element.style.display = "";
      
  }
};

ko.applyBindings({ booleanValue: ko.observable(true) });
```

```css
.block {
  display: block !important;
}

.hide-important {
  display: none !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div class="block" data-bind="importantVisible: booleanValue">
  importantVisible binding
</div>


<div class="block" data-bind="visible: booleanValue">
  visible binding
</div>

<div class="block" data-bind="css: {'hide-important': !booleanValue()}">
  css binding
</div>

<button data-bind="click: booleanValue.bind(null, !booleanValue())">toggle</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `css` data Binding. The `css` binding adds or removes one or more named CSS classes to the associated DOM element.

```
<div class="col-xs-1 hidden-md hidden-lg" data-bind="css: YourCss"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be to wrap the element in another element and bind the wrapper element's visibility using Knockout. E.g.:

```
<div data-bind="visible: BooleanValue">
    <div class="col-xs-1 hidden-md hidden-lg"></div>
</div>
```

Altneratively, to avoid breaking your page's layout you can use [Knockout's containerless "if" syntax](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/if-binding.html) like this:

```
<!-- ko if: BooleanValue -->
    <div class="col-xs-1 hidden-md hidden-lg"></div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

These are both less elegant solutions than the answers already proposed but are probably quicker and easier to implement and in my opinion have the advantage of avoiding the potentially murky world of using `!important` to override Bootstrap's styling.